# How to handle possible NULL in a Trigger Updating a table without a Primary Key

Tags: postgresql, trigger, query, update

I'm using Postgres Triggers to keep two tables in sync for a short term migration. However, I have one join table that doesn't have a primary key, but two columns that function as a composite primary key, but both of those columns allow `NULL` values.

For tables with regular `NOT NULL` primary keys, a trigger that calls a function like this works well:

```sql
UPDATE "foo"
SET
    "bar_id" = NEW."bar_id",
    "baz_id" = NEW."baz_id",
    "created_at" = NEW."created_at",
    "updated_at" = NEW."updated_at"
WHERE
    "foo"."bar_id" = OLD."bar_id"
AND "foo"."baz_id" = OLD."baz_id"
```

I update the 2nd table with all the `NEW` values from the first table, where the old "primary key" values match. However, If either of the keys are `NULL` then nothing gets updated, since `NULL != NULL`.

I'm considering handling this by adding several `IS NULL` checks, like:

```sql
UPDATE "foo"
SET
    "bar_id" = NEW."bar_id",
    "baz_id" = NEW."baz_id",
    "created_at" = NEW."created_at",
    "updated_at" = NEW."updated_at"
WHERE
    ("foo"."bar_id" = OLD."bar_id" OR ("foo"."bar_id" IS NULL AND OLD."bar_id" IS NULL))
AND ("foo"."baz_id" = OLD."baz_id" OR ("foo"."baz_id" IS NULL AND OLD."baz_id" IS NULL))
```

Is there a better way to handle possible `NULL`s in `WHERE` clauses like these?

Answer (score -1):

See if [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-comparison.html) serves your purpose.

IS (NOT) DISTINCT FROM is the equivalent of the `=` operator, but also works with NULLs. If one input is NULL and one input is not, the result is `TRUE`, or `FALSE` when both inputs are NULL.

For example, you would use it like this in your update statement.

```
UPDATE "foo"
SET
    "bar_id" = NEW."bar_id",
    "baz_id" = NEW."baz_id",
    "created_at" = NEW."created_at",
    "updated_at" = NEW."updated_at"
WHERE "foo"."bar_id" IS NOT DISTINCT FROM OLD."bar_id"
    AND "foo"."baz_id" IS NOT DISTINCT FROM OLD."baz_id"
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Links are great to support answers. However, they should only be needed to validate from what you've shared. With a well answered question, someone should not need to hit the link, unless they don't believe the answer or want a more in-depth understanding of the concept.